# Can I export both component and const

Tags: reactjs

I have two js files. One with the code for AComponent. And in the second js, I have imported the AComponent file and additionally, I have written:

```
const Ctext = (props) => (....)
```

How to export both?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AComponent from "./image";
const Ctext = (props) => (
<div>
<h5 className="card-title">Image n Text Card</h5>
 <p className="card-text">{props.dataFromParent.textContent}</p>
</div>
);

export default Ctext;
export const props => <AComponent />;
```

Comment: I have two js files. One with the code for AComponent. And in the second js, I have imported the AComponent file and additionally, I have written const Ctext = (props) => (....)


    export default props => <AComponent />;
    enter code here

How to export both?

Answer (score 1):

This line might be giving you problems

```
export const props => <AComponent />;
```

You aren't defining a name for that function being exported. You can try,

```
export const aComponentFunction = props => <AComponent {...props} />; //<-- I added the props too
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot export an unnamed function, you have to name it otherwise you cannot import it in other file:

`const myFunc = props => <AComponent>`

Then you can export myFunc.

I think it is better that a file exports only one Component, anyway if you wish to export more than one component or function I would group them in an objext and export that object as default export:

`const objectToExport = { myFunc, myComponent };
export default objectToExport`

Also take care that you can only have one default export per file